# outlook shows wrong time from ICal

Tags: asp.net, outlook, icalendar

I got in to a strange problem.I am creating an ICal file through razor code and when i download ICal from wesbite it shows wrong time in it.

However when I open it with a notepad correct time is printer there.
to describe this in detail I will produce a sample.
Ical open in notepad

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130107T150000Z
DTEND:20130107T170000Z
DTSTAMP:20130107T131549Z
ORGANIZER;CN=it@rk.com:mailto:it@rk.com
UID:u20vfrto8rfd9cscp52sn9o@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:
DESCRIPTION: INGBOARD IS IN ENGLISH.\n\nLand: Denmark\n
LOCATION:
STATUS:
SUMMARY:US Company
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

In this time is correct start time as 15.00 and end time as 17.00

When I open this in Outlook it shows start time as 8.30 PM  and end Time as 10.30 PM  which is wrong.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start and end times are explicitly specified in UTC (due to the trailing Z). If Outlook is displaying them in *local* time, that would explain the difference. It sounds like Outlook is in an Indian time zone (which is UTC+05:30 at the moment).

You may well want to specify a local start/end time, and separately the time zone of the event. (If you don't specify the time zone, it won't start at a specific instant in time, which would be unusual for most events.)

Comment: @AKS: Well when does the event *actually* start? 15:00 local time, or 15:00 UTC? If you're going to include `Z` in the format string, the `DateTime` value had better be in UTC to start with...

Comment: this is how i added times to ical
(DateTime)course.CourseEndDate).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") can you suggest any change so taht i can change this utc settings to UTC+01:00.thanks

Comment: @AKS: Removing your previous comment and adding a similar one doesn't really help. Why would you want UTC+1? That sounds like it wouldn't be suitable at all...

Comment: i need event to start at  UTC + 01:00 which is danish time.
do i need to add +1 hour on each time with code or is there any quick fix to change utc to danish time zone like removing 'z'and adding some thing else.and your confusion got reasons,that i am developing a danish site from india.

Comment: @AKS: It would probably be best to use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` in that case. Alternatively, output the *local* time (no Z) and the time zone as a DTZONE.